# ubuntu 15.04 problem with typing password to decrypt the disk

Tags: ubuntu, boot, password, encryption

I have a stupid problem after installation of ubuntu15.04 on lenovo e450. I install ubuntu with full-encryption disk option, but I have a problem. I cannot type password to this password box, but when I click power button ( hard reset). I have a more primitive view for password (without this fancy box for password) and I can type my password. Everyone know any workaround ?
And I need to do this hard restart, every time when I turn on my laptop...
I will be gratefull for any help.

Comment: Does this [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1386005) corresponds to your situation? It is reported for Ubuntu 14.10, though

Comment: @dave_alcarin this bugreport fit me perfectly...

Comment: I switch to text-mode boot and update grub, and this workaround is working ;) thanks for help, this link show me the way :PP

Comment: Then post your found solution as an answer to this question and accept it, so that other people can see the workaround faster